# FileManager.createDirectory fails with NSCocoaErrorDomain Code: 518

Tags: ios, url, temporary-directory

I'm doing

```
    let tempDirectory = URL(string: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())video/")!
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
            at: tempDirectory,
            withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    } catch { report(error) }
```

and that's often throwing an NSCocoaErrorDomain Code: 518.

Any idea of the reason? I thought that could because there's already something there, so I added

```
    var isDir: ObjCBool = false
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(
        atPath: tempDirectory.absoluteString,
        isDirectory: &isDir
    ) {
        if isDir.boolValue {
            print("Temp directory exists on launch")
        }
        else {
            print("Temp directory exists on launch and is a file")
        }
        return
    }
```

but that doesn't seem to catch anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your building of `tempDirectory` isn't correct. You want:

```
let tempDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()). appendingPathComponent("video")
```

The issue with your code is that you were not passing a value URL string to `URL(string:)`. Since you have a file path you need to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`. And build paths/URLs using the provided methods to ensure slashes and other parts are added correctly.

Print your value of `tempDirectory` from your original code and then print the new value from the code in my answer. Note the key difference.

Your URL will be something like:

> /var/...

and it may be missing the slash before "video".

The correct file URL will be something like:

> file:///var/...